# Passing Python functions from YAML file

Tags: python, yaml

I have a YAML script where the users can define some parameters. They can also state in the YAML file a custom function they want to apply. For example:

```
processes:
    args1: 10
    args2: 5
    funct: np.sum
```

This YAML will be passed to a function like this:

```
def custom_func(args1, args2, funct):
    return funct(args1, args2)
```

With the YAML example above, I expect `custom_func()` to execute `np.sum(10,5)`. How can I make the data in YAML file to be parsed as Callable? `eval()` probably does the job but it might have security issue. Is there any proper way? Thanks!

Comment: Dictionaries? Store `np.sum` (as a function, not called) in the value spot and index to it when running your function

Comment: can you pls elaborate more?

Comment: I'll answer instead....

Comment: You can always try to use the `getattr(callable, 'function name')`. Here, `callable` can be replaced by the function np.sum directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also load the function given its Python dotted path.

However, this only gets the function and calls it, it does not try to figure out calling signature, which is `np.sum([5,10])`, not `np.sum(10,5)`

```
from yaml import safe_load as yload
from importlib import import_module

def load_func(dotpath : str):
    """ load function in module.  function is right-most segment """
    module_, func = dotpath.rsplit(".", maxsplit=1)
    m = import_module(module_)
    return getattr(m, func)
    
yaml = """
processes:
    args1: 10
    args2: 5

    #gotta give real package name, not `np`
    funct: numpy.sum
"""

di = yload(yaml)
pr = di["processes"]
func = load_func(pr["funct"])
array = [pr["args1"], pr["args2"]]

print (f"{func=} {func(array)=}")
```

#### output:

```
func=<function sum at 0x106645e50> func(array)=15
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `eval` and `exec` are both bad practices. Good that you know that :D

You can use dictionaries to do this.
What you can do is define a dictionary and make the key the `funct` value in YAML. The value will be an uncalled function. This is similar to a variable.

```py
funct_parser = {
    "np.sum": np.sum # Notice how this doesn't have ()
}
```

You can then use `funct` against the dictionary to call the proper method. Something like the following:

```py
def custom_func(args1, args2, funct):
    my_func = funct_parser[str(funct)] # This will cause my_func to be a copy of `np.sum`.
    return my_func(args1, args2) # Call my_func
```

BTW, you don't really have to do `custom_func` on multiple lines, I just did so to explain it better.

**Alternative choice:**
If you don't feel like hardcoding every single part in a dictionary, you can use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr).

```py
# This code assumes you have numpy imported as np (You can always change it)
def custom_func(args1, args2, funct):
    funct = funct.split("np.")[0] # Will work for np. You can always change to other modules when needed.
    return getattr(np, funct)
```

Comment: Is it a pre-defined dictionary where I need to list all possible ```funct``` arguments? What if it can be any numpy operation (or even tensorflow)?

Comment: @eng2019 You can use `getattr` for objects and modules. I apologize for not thinking of that sooner....