# How to create click Command using API?

Tags: python, python-click

I am trying to create a python click Command using the API instead of decorators. This is because I am trying to create commands dynamically from a `yaml` file.

**parsed yaml file**:

```
{'adhoc': {'args': ['abcd',
                    {'analytic-type': {'type': 'click.Choice(["prof", "fac"], '
                                               'case_sensitive=False)'}},
                    {'lobplat': {'default': 'ALL',
                                 'type': 'click.Choice(["A","B","C","D","ALL",],case_sensitive=False)'}}],
           'options': [{'environment': {'alias': '-e',
                                        'envvar': 'env',
                                        'show_default': 'loc',
                                        'type': 'click.Choice(["a", "b", '
                                                '"c", "d", "e"], '
                                                'case_sensitive=False)'}},
                       {'email': {'alias': '-m',
                                  'default': 'test@test.com',
                                  'multiple': True}},
                       {'runtype': {'alias': '-r',
                                    'default': 'ADHOC',
                                    'type': 'click.Choice(["TEST","ADHOC","SCHEDULED"], '
                                            'case_sensitive=False)'}}],
           'script': 'nohup '
                     '/path/to/script/script'}}
```

At the top level it defines a command called `adhoc` which has 3 parts:

1. Arguments (*args*)
2. Options (*options*)
3. Script (This is the function of the command)

Both argument and options have a list of different Parameters that I want to create.
Here is the class that I have written:

```
import click
import yaml

class Commander():
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def run_command(self, script):
        pass


    def str_to_class(self,classname):
        return getattr(sys.modules[__name__], classname)

    def create_args(self,arguments):

        all_args = []

        for arg in arguments:
            if isinstance(arg, str):
                all_args.append(click.Argument([arg]))
            else:
                attributes = arg[list(arg.keys())[0]]
                print(attributes)
                all_args.append(click.Argument([arg],**attributes))

        return all_args


    def convert_to_command(self,yaml):

        for key, value in yaml.items():
            name = key
            script = value["script"]
            options = value["options"]
            args = value["args"]

            click_arg = self.create_args(args)
            print(click_arg)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    commander = Commander()
    yaml = {'adhoc': {'args': ['abcd',
                    {'analytic-type': {'type': 'click.Choice(["prof", "fac"], '
                                                'case_sensitive=False)'}},
                    {'lobplat': {'default': 'ALL',
                                    'type': 'click.Choice(["A","B","C","D","ALL",],case_sensitive=False)'}}],
            'options': [{'environment': {'alias': '-e',
                                        'envvar': 'env',
                                        'show_default': 'loc',
                                        'type': 'click.Choice(["a", "b", '
                                                '"c", "d", "e"], '
                                                'case_sensitive=False)'}},
                        {'email': {'alias': '-m',
                                    'default': 'test@test.com',
                                    'multiple': True}},
                        {'runtype': {'alias': '-r',
                                    'default': 'ADHOC',
                                    'type': 'click.Choice(["TEST","ADHOC","SCHEDULED"], '
                                            'case_sensitive=False)'}}],
            'script': 'nohup '
                        '/path/to/script/script'}}

    commander.convert_to_command(yaml)
```

These functions are not complete. Currently I am working on writing a function to create Arguments out of the Yaml dictionary. However upon running `create_command()` I get the following error:

```
  File "/project/helper/commander.py", line 111, in <module>
    commander.convert_to_command(yaml)
  File "/project/hassle/helper/commander.py", line 45, in convert_to_command
    click_arg = self.create_args(args)
  File "/project/hassle/helper/commander.py", line 32, in create_args
    all_args.append(click.Argument([arg],**attributes))
  File "/home/myself/miniconda3/envs/py_copier/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 2950, in __init__
    super().__init__(param_decls, required=required, **attrs)
  File "/home/myself/miniconda3/envs/py_copier/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 2073, in __init__
    param_decls or (), expose_value
  File "/home/myself/miniconda3/envs/py_copier/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 2983, in _parse_decls
    name = name.replace("-", "_").lower()
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Comment: You should provide minimal reproducible example, so we can run what you run and get the error you get. Please update your question. Nevertheless, the error tells you, that name is not a string, as you expect, but a dictionary, but with the information you provided, I cannot help you any further.

Comment: Hi @wankata Thanks for your input. I have updated my example so that you can run it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the updated code snippet!

Now, what is going on here:

```py
all_args.append(click.Argument([arg],**attributes))
```

Where `arg` is:

```py
{'analytic-type': {'type': 'click.Choice(["prof", "fac"], case_sensitive=False)'}}
```

but if you look at the [documentation about the `click.Argument` class](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/api/#click.Argument), you'll see the following:

> class click.Argument(param_decls, required=None, **attrs)
>
> param_decls (Sequence[str]) –

You made the sequence part, but inside the sequence you still have the dict, instead of the string(s) with the argument name(s). So you should provide click.Argument with something like this:

```py
[list(arg.keys())[0]]
# e.g.
all_args.append(click.Argument([list(arg.keys())[0]],**attributes))
```

But now you have another problem:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

which is now related to your attributes, as you pass the function as string, but click expects callable. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67442071/passing-python-functions-from-yaml-file). It should resolve the issue.

PS: I've just tested it with a quick and dirty `eval` and it works, so when you fix the callable problem in a proper way, you are good to move on.